# Telegram bot - api methods not working on server

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I am trying to create a Telegram Bot. I follow [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJBYojK7DO4). my codes are working in localhost, but when I put them on server the result is different. this code just call `getUpdates` method of Telegram api.

Code :

```
<?php 

    $botToken = "146158152:AAHO**********-L3xF08RN7H0xK8E";
    $website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken;

    $update = file_get_contents($website."/getUpdates");

    var_dump($update);

?>
```

Localhost result :

```
string(616) "{"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":35****293, "message":{"message_id":1,"from":{"id":95*****4,"first_name":"Mahmood","last_name":"Kohansal","username":"mahmoodkohansal"},"chat":{"id":95*****4,"first_name":"Mahmood","last_name":"Kohansal","username":"mahmoodkohansal","type":"private"},"date":1448737853,"text":"\/start"}},{"update_id":356676294, "message":{"message_id":2,"from":{"id":95*****4,"first_name":"Mahmood","last_name":"Kohansal","username":"mahmoodkohansal"},"chat":{"id":95881214,"first_name":"Mahmood","last_name":"Kohansal","username":"mahmoodkohansal","type":"private"},"date":1448737855,"text":"1"}}]}"
```

and Server result :

```
bool(false)
```

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Are you sure your server allow connections to https://api.telegram.org?

Answer (score 1):

If your code works in localhost, the first assumption would be that your server was not successful in establishing a connection to the bot api.
Perhaps you should put it in an if statement.

```
$token = "your token";
$website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token;

if($updates = file_get_contents($website."/getUpdates"))
{
  echo "Connection made";
}
else
{
  echo "Fail";
}
```

Also can you make sure a webHook isn't set? getUpdates method does not return results if a webHook is set.

Comment: If running the method from localhost agains telegram servers return the correct answer, it means that the webhook isn't set.

Comment: That...and the telegram server has been buggy today, been hearing a lot of complaints about the server being down/slow.

Answer (score 0):

PHP file_get_contents method was the problem. I found the same problem with this method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688966/php-json-returning-boolfalse), and use the solution to solve my problem.